# $\|A-B\|^2 = ?$

Tags: matrices

We know that if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
(x-y)^2 = x^2 -2xy + y^2
\end{equation}
If $x,y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
\begin{equation}
|x-y|^2=|x|^2 - 2 \ x \cdot y +|y|^2.
\end{equation}
where $x\cdot y$ is the usual scalar product. We know that there are several ways to define $\|A\|$ when $A$ is a matrix, for example
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = \sup  \{ |Ax|: |x|=1\}
\end{equation}
Is there a similar formula as above? This is a formula to $\|A-B\|^2?$

Comment: Whenever the norm is induced by an inner product $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$; we can write $$\lVert x-y\rVert^2 =\lVert x\rVert^2-2\langle x,y\rangle+\lVert y\rVert^2$$ Note your two equations are particular cases of this where $\langle x,y\rangle =x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$. In particular $\langle x,y\rangle=xy$ is an inner product in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is $\|A\|$ induced by an inner product? What is $\langle A,B\rangle?$

Answer (score 4):

If the norm is induced by some inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$, it must obey the parallelogram law:

\begin{align*}
\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 &= \|x\|^2 + 2\langle x, y\rangle + \|y\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - 2\langle x, y\rangle + \|y\|^2\\
&= 2\|x\|^2 + 2\|y\|^2
\end{align*}

A first indication that something is wrong is that the two matrices $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right]$ have the same norm. Indeed,

$$\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right] \right\|^2+\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right] \right\|^2 = 2,$$
$$2\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\right\|^2 +2\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right] \right\|^2 = 4,$$
violating the law.

Comment: Very good your observation, thank you. But you do not answer my ask yet. My ask is motivated by the fact that  in my calculations appear something like $\|A-B\|$ and an estimate for this.

Comment: He did, if your norm comes from an inner product, the formula holds, if not, then what is $x\cdot y$ supposed to be?

Comment: An general _estimate_ would be $|\,||A||-||B||\;|\leq ||A-B||\leq ||A||+||B||$.